# Unique function leaves out column

Tags: r, matrix, dataset

Say I use the UNIQUE function of **R** to create a script to pull out particular columns of a premade dataframe to make a new one:

```
SUPSCIARIDS<-unique(SuperiorSciarids[,c(36,2,3,4:34)])

36-LOGID

2-Decay

3-Diameter

4:34 are the species
```

Why would it be do you think the new data frame does not show column 2?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.....that annoying dummy column "row.names" that often appears before column one.

I was considering row.names as the first column in my matrix, thus if I add 1 to the beginning of the column query it brings up the Decay variable in my unique table, BINGO! and how embarassing......>

```
SUPSCIARIDS<-unique(SuperiorSciarids[,c(35,1,2,3,4:34)])
```